# Is there a faster way to sum up an arithmetic sequence of numbers in Python?

Tags: python

```
total = 0
for i in range(0, some upper bound):
    total += i
```

Sorry if this is basic but I have a lot of these and they're taking up more room than is comfortable.

Comment: You want a faster or shorter code?

Comment: Shorter and faster ideally! Is there a tradeoff?

Comment: Yes, solution with `sum` is more readable and the `Gauss` function is faster.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
total = sum(range(upper))
```

or

```
total = upper * (upper - 1) / 2
```

The first one is Python, the second one Gauss.

EDIT: When not starting at zero:

```
total = sum(range(lower, upper))
```

or, again according to Gauss, do the same with `upper` and substract the same for `lower`:

```
total = upper * (upper - 1) / 2 - lower * (lower - 1) / 2
```

If you are on Python 2.x, replace all `range` with `xrange`.

Comment: This works great! Thank you. For situations where I am not starting at 0 do I just do sum(range(lower, upper)) ?

Comment: You should always use generators instead of iterables if you consume them afterwards. In this case you should use `xrange` instead of `range`.

Comment: What is the difference between xrange and range?

Comment: @user1435323 xrange/range: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Use_xrange_instead_of_range

Comment: @user1435323 Basically yes, but you're better off with `xrange` (because of less memory consumption).

Comment: So if xrange is faster why would I ever use range?

Comment: @eumiro I don't agree with your explanation, both is Python ;-) Please clarify this.

Comment: @ms4py - OP's solution works. My first proposal is better, because it uses special Python features with the same mathematical concept, while my second proposal is better, because it uses special mathematical concept with the same level of Python knowledge.

Comment: @eumiro I know ;-) You should not clarify this for me but in your answer. The statement "The first one is Python, the second one Gauss" is just wrong...

Comment: You would use `range` because you actually need the `list` for some other purpose.

Answer (score 2):

`total = some_upper_bound * (some_upper_bound -1) / 2`

if `lower_bound != 0`:

`total = (some_upper_bound - lower_bound) * (some_upper_bound + lower_bound - 1) / 2`

*Update:* I would've deleted my answer as it is practically an exact copy of part of the accepted answer (although I answered independently). There is, however, one - very small, but theoretically interesting improvement when `lower_bound` is involved: my answer contains only two multiplications / divisions (which are relatively more expensive than additions/subtractions) while the other answer contains four.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on eumiro. You may want to write a method that encapsulates the Gauss method for clarity. I would suggest something like this (written in Groovy because I don't know Python syntax):

```
public int sumUpToBoundary(def upper_bound){
    return (upper_bound) * (upper_bound - 1) / 2;
}

public int sumBetween(def lower_bound, def upper_bound){
    return sumUpToBoundary(upper_bound) - sumUpToBoundary(lower_bound);
}

public void someOtherMethod() {
    int total = sumUpToBoundary(some_upper_bound);
    int total2 = sumBetween(some_lower_bound, some_upper_bound);
}
```

UPDATE: @mspy noted that my method signatures weren't in the style of Python. I've updated the example to groovy which supports somewhat more Python-like syntax.

Comment: Good intention, but this Java example is strictly against Python principles. Mainly data types in names is a very bad idea, we are doing duck typing here ;-)

Comment: @ms4py - While I would expect the reader to be able to translate my answer into the proper style for their language, I take your point that I didn't answer in Python. I've edited my answer to be in Groovy which supports a more Python-y syntax. (Please remove -1).